# Bash parameter substitution in xinitrc

Tags: bash, shell, parameters, command-line-arguments

I am trying to edit my `.xinitrc` file so that `startx` can run with a parameter telling it which window manager/desktop to use, but fall back to a default one if none are provided. `.xinitrc` is a shell script.

What I have used is this code:

```
desktop=${desktop:-startkde}
exec $desktop
```

The idea is that running `startx desktop=fluxbox` will launch a different desktop then the default provided, however this does not work. Can anyone see what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
desktop=fluxbox startx
```

Environment variables are set by putting them before the command name; everything after the command name is just arguments to the command.

Comment: Thanks! That did it :) Although I find the solution weird.. A lot of scripts use the variable=value method after and not before the command name. How exactly do they do this?

Comment: That only works if the command itself treats arguments of that form specially, and sets variables from them. For instance, `make` and `awk` do this, although they're setting their internal variables, not environment variables.